# summation, any similar function

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

How can I calculate the second sigma:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiWMm.png)

**Note**: I was told to use Taylor series of: $e^x, sin(x), cos(x), ln(1+x), arctg(x)$

Edit: the problem is that I don't see any of the sigmas similar to a taylor series of a given function to use

Comment: Notice that $\frac{(-1)^n}{n\cdot 3^n}=\frac{(-1)^n(\frac13)^n}n$.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is from the taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$:
$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^n}{n}$$
In your case, $x = \frac{1}{3}$ and one needs to add a negative sign to correct between $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{n-1}$, so your second sum is $-\ln(1+\frac{1}{3}) = \ln(\frac{3}{4})$. For the first sum, use the fact that
$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$